# 'Object not found' error when trying to run randomForest

Tags: r, random-forest

Im trying to run a random forest in the data below

```
train_data<-structure(c(38, 184, 38, 7, 38, 380.95, 159, 989.99, 249, 449.99, 
15.3642666666667, 27, 15.6, 14, 15.6, 4, 14.7785547785548, 32, 
4, 16, 268.711491442543, 268.711491442543, 1, 64, 1, 6, 6, 1, 
1, 1, 27, 27, 11, 7, 39, 14, 14, 3, 2, 8, 13, 13, 1, 2, 1, 29, 
29, 8, 6, 17, 2, 53, 15, 7, 2, 23, 2, 17, 1, 3, 63, 41, 37, 8, 
31, 362, 362, 171, 13, 187, 7, 7, 8, 4, 8, 2, 2, 6, 7, 6, 4.32753036437247, 
5, 4.5, 4.4, 4.2, 281.983805668016, 2, 7, 1562, 193, 1.7983651226158, 
1.7983651226158, 2, 2, 2), dim = c(5L, 19L), dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("Model Name", "Price", "Screen Size", "RAM", "Storage Size", 
    "Storage Type", "CPU Model", "Operating System", "Graphics Card Description", 
    "Graphics Coprocessor", "Special Feature", "Screen Resolution", 
    "CPU Speed", "ASIN", "Seller Business Name", "Seller Business Address", 
    "Review Star", "Total Review", "TouchScreen")))
```

but I get:

```
model <- randomForest(Price ~ ., data = train_data, ntree = 100)
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'Model Name' not found
```

while I obviously have `Model Name` in my data

Comment: Wrap your data in `data.frame` -  `randomForest(...,  data = data.frame(train_data), ...)`

Comment: To complete the answer, indeed your dataset is of class "matrix" while as recommended in the documentation data should be a data frame : https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/randomForest/versions/4.7-1.1/topics/randomForest